# Updating SLOT_DURATION on Mainnet - Seeking Assistance!

Tags: runtime, storage, validator, blockchain, solo-chain

We are facing a challenge regarding our mainnet and we need the guidance and expertise of the community. Currently, we are looking to update the SLOT_DURATION to optimize the performance of our network.

We would appreciate guidance, insights, or links to resources that can assist us in this process without compromising existing data. We want to ensure a smooth transition and minimize any risk of data loss.

We thank you in advance for your help!

The best approach to update without losing data. The network is still relatively new with few users.

We hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think updating this constant is possible without a hard fork, as it is both a node and runtime upgrade. But if your primary worry is data loss, it is not an issue. You can always take a snapshot of the network, and make that be the genesis of the new one.

Comment: hi @kianenigma. How do we take a snapshot of the network? How do we run the chain with the new genesis spec but still keep the old ledger from the snapshot?